# Cutting shaped holes in polygons in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

Assume a filled polygon created with CCDrawNode:

```
CCDrawNode *polygon = [CCDrawNode node];

CGPoint points[4];
points[0] = ccp(-20.0, -20.0);
points[1] = ccp(20.0, -20.0);
points[2] = ccp(20.0, 20.0);
points[3] = ccp(-20.0, 20.0);

[polygon drawPolyWithVerts:points count:4 fillColor:[CCColor blackColor] borderWidth:0.0 borderColor:[CCColor clearColor]];
[self addChild:polygon];
```

How do I cut shaped holes in it so I can achieve an effect similar to this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHVT1.png

Holes will be generated dynamically and in various configurations so preparing a set of pre-made textures is not an option.

I had no luck trying to create the holes as polygons using CCDrawNode and applying a blending function:

```
CCDrawNode *circle = [CCDrawNode node];
[circle drawDot:ccp(0.0, 0.0) radius:10.0 color:[CCColor whiteColor]];
[circle setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA}];
[self addChild:circle];
```

or

```
...
[polygon setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA}];
[polygon drawDot:ccp(0.0, 0.0) radius:10.0 color:[CCColor whiteColor]];
[self addChild:polygon];
```

I believe I tried every combination of blending modes, not finding the right one.

I'm obviously doing something wrong as this looks like something that can be achieved using blending modes. Or do I have to override the `draw` method and apply some OpenGL ES code? I tried playing with OpenGL but ended up accomplishing nothing. Also, I'm not sure what's the preferred way of mixing OpenGL ES (2.0+) with Cocos2D, as for what I know I should refrain from doing it in the "immediate mode".

But if it's not the proper way of doing it, I'd like to know your suggestions.

By the way -- CCDrawNode doesn't seem to support the `opacity` property out of the box. Is there a way to enable it? It just renders its contents at 100% opacity, regardless of the property's value.

I'm using Cocos2D 3.0 on iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the [CCClippingNode](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/Classes/CCClippingNode.html) class. Here's an example:

```
// Square-shaped hole
CCDrawNode *square = [CCDrawNode node];
CGPoint squarePoints[4] = {ccp(-20.0, -20.0), ccp(20.0, -20.0), ccp(20.0, 20.0), ccp(-20.0, 20.0)};
[square drawPolyWithVerts:squarePoints count:4 fillColor:[CCColor blackColor] borderWidth:0.0 borderColor:[CCColor clearColor]];
square.position = ccp(0.0, 0.0);

// Triangle-shaped hole
CCDrawNode *triangle = [CCDrawNode node];
CGPoint trianglePoints[3] = {ccp(-10.0, 25.0), ccp(10.0, 25.0), ccp(0.0, 25.0 + 10.0 * sqrt(3.0))};
[triangle drawPolyWithVerts:trianglePoints count:3 fillColor:[CCColor blackColor] borderWidth:0.0 borderColor:[CCColor clearColor]];
triangle.position = ccp(0.0, 0.0);

// Prepare your stencil
CCNode *stencil = [CCNode node];
[stencil addChild:square];
[stencil addChild:triangle];

// Create a clipping node with the prepared stencil
CCClippingNode *clippingNode = [CCClippingNode clippingNodeWithStencil:stencil];

// Setting the clipping mode to inverted will result in the clipping node drawing its contents everywhere BUT the stencil's non-transparent areas
clippingNode.inverted = YES;

// Create your polygon
CCDrawNode *polygon = [CCDrawNode node];
CGPoint polygonPoints[4] = {ccp(-50.0, -50.0), ccp(40.0, -40.0), ccp(50.0, 50.0), ccp(-40.0, 40.0)};
[polygon drawPolyWithVerts:polygonPoints count:4 fillColor:[CCColor blackColor] borderWidth:0.0 borderColor:[CCColor clearColor]];
polygon.position = ccp(0.0, 0.0);
[clippingNode addChild:polygon];

// Now the clipping node should contain your polygon with shaped-holes in it
```

If I recall correctly, filled circles created with `CCDrawNode` will not work well in stencils so you might need to create your own circle-drawing class or use a texture.

Comment: Indeed, I needed to create an additional class for drawing circles. Thanks you so much! I should have looked through all the built-in classes.

Comment: b2PolygonShape shape;
  int max = 8;
  float ang = 2*3.1415926/max;
  float len = radius/PTM_RATIO/cos(ang/2);
  b2Vec2* new1Vecs = (b2Vec2*)calloc(max, sizeof(b2Vec2));
  for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
   new1Vecs[i] = b2Vec2(len*cos(ang*i),len*sin(ang*i));
  }
  shape.Set(new1Vecs, max);